# Springboot mail

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, mandrill

This is the first time I'm trying to send mail, using spring-boot-starter-mail.I dont get any error but while sending my mail but i could not see any mail to my TO id.

application.properties

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.mandrillapp.com
spring.mai.username = lending@vit.in    
spring.mail.password = ********
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
```

My Application Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mail"})
 public class MailServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(MailServiceApplication.class);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MailServiceApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet(){
    ServletRegistrationBean register = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(),"/*");
    register.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyInitialization.class.getName());
    return register;
}
}
```

JerseyInitialization.class

```
@Component
public class JerseyInitialization extends ResourceConfig{

public JerseyInitialization(){
    super();
    this.packages("com.mail.interfaces");
    System.out.println("111");
     //register(GenericFilter.class);
    // property(ServerProperties.MONITORING_STATISTICS_ENABLED, true);
}
}
```

Controller Class:

```
@RestController
@Path("/mail")
public class MailResource {

@Autowired
MailSendInter mailInter;

@GET
@Path("/send")
public String sendMail(){
    System.out.println("inside the resource Class");
    boolean result = mailInter.send("aravind11081990@gmail.com", "Welcome Mail","Wlcome to the lending system");
    if(result){
        return "ok";    
    }else{
        return "failure";
    }

}
}
```

Interface Class:

```
@Service
public interface MailSendInter {

public boolean send(String to, String subject, String body);
}
```

ImplementationClass:

```
@Component
public class MailSendImplementation implements MailSendInter{

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

@Override
public boolean send(String to, String subject, String body) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean result = false;
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try{

        MimeMessageHelper helper ;
        helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setText(body, true);
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        result = true;
    }catch(MessagingException mex){
        result = false;
        System.err.println("Expection"+mex);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Pom.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>MailService</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MailService</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I'm using Mandrill for sending mail

URL:https://www.mandrill.com
Username : lending@vit.in
Password: ********

Host : smtp.mandrillapp.com
Port : 587
SMTP Username :  lending@vit.in
SMTP Password : ********

Can some one help to figure out the error

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Instead of dumping all the code, it would be much easier to provide a link to a (github) repository so that we can actually try it. I wouldn't use `1.4.3` but I'd use the mail api provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: If you're using Mandrill, also remember that you need to verify your vit.in domain before you can actually send any email: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582247-About-Domain-Verification